# Dropdown/hover menu

Tags: html, css

The problem is this: When I use my cursor over the dropdown place, I can't select any of the options that I have in it, because when I take the cursor off the dropdown place, the options disappear.

The "C" is where my cursor is.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q89lj.jpg - Before I move the cursor
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj9AH.jpg - After I move it

CSS code:

```
ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        width: 150px;
    }

    ul li {
        position: relative;
    }

    li ul {
        position: absolute;
        left: 149px;
        top: 0;
        display: none;
    }

    ul li a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #E2144A;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    }
    li:hover ul { display: block; }
```

HTML code:

```
<ul id="left" class='column'> 
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">O que Fazemos?</a> 
  <ul> 
    <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Hospedagem</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">SEO</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Sistemas</a></li> 
  </ul> 
</li>

<li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting a `left:` to a smaller value, like `80px` or so

```
li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 80px;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Ahh I see now, thanks a lot! I didn't know that the space between the options and the menu could influence it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there's a gap between the navigation, and the dropdown menu. That gap, however, is not caused by your CSS code, so you should check other parts of your stylesheet to see if you can remove it.

Comment: Based on the code you provided, it works fine. You need to check the other CSS as @Pandaqi suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the space between navigation and dropdown using margins, try padding instead. That way the browser will treat it as part of the object.

for example, if you had:

```
*{
    margin:10px;
}
```

You could change it to:

```
    *{
    padding:10px;
}
```

Alternatively, you could override the space on just the navigation items.